# Why postgres calculate percentage wrong (based on columns result)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to get % of discount between two columns, first problem which i was solved is that other column may be 0 or null,
Now when I calculate it it always give me 100 or 0 as a result of column 'discount'

```
Product.active.select("*, 100-(price/(
(CASE WHEN(market_price IS NULL OR market_price = 0)
THEN price ELSE market_price END)))*100 
AS discount")
```

All the results was 0 or 100 :\

Tried to solve with sub function but still gave me same wrong percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after going to psql console, i've found that someone made `price` and `original_price` are `integer` and not `numeric`, this caused bad rounding.

Solved by declaring column type as numeric:

```
Product.active.select("*, (100 - ((price::numeric / 
(CASE WHEN(market_price IS NULL OR market_price = 0) 
THEN price ELSE market_price END)::numeric)*100.0))
AS discount")
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the bad database schema with a migration, rather than adding this hacky workaround for your specific query?

Comment: Likewise, I would advise fixing the dodgy `0` and `NULL` database values for `market_price`, rather than requiring such a workaround in your query.